# Render specific item from array using *ngFor index in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I am rendering a list using `*ngFor`. I only want the next item to be rendered using `index`. I have tried a number of things but can't get it to work:

```html
Next: {{ exhibit{{ i + 1 }}.fields.artist }}
```

```html
Next: {{ exhibit[i + 1].fields.artist }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add more details? Describe the use case.

Comment: We need to see the `*ngFor` loop markup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do you want to render a list like this, but you can accomplish this using ngFor as below. You need to write the entire template expression inside double curly braces instead of just index.

```
Next: {{ exhibit[i + 1].fields.artist }}
```

Please find proof of concept here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwxgee